# schedule mysql table empty every 24 hours

Tags: mysql, database

I am having problem with mysql database at one of my sites, its related to database size,

in my database i have a table that store info about every hit on the site (form which ip,time country,referrer,etc) the problem that this table get boated in size quickly and i found that when i each about 100 mb then the server load become very high and i cant even browse the site.

i am thinking about emptying this table every 24 hour automatically but i dont know where to start.

what do u think? is there is any thing better than this approach.

Comment: cron job is ur solution

Comment: you can use available scheduler or can go for cron job

Comment: should i write php script that empty the table? then schedule it every time period?

Comment: you do not need php for this, you can do this with bash, but if you more comfortable with php, you can write php script.

Answer (score 0):

i managed to do this with both cron job + php :

here is the script:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbName");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}    
$sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE tableName";
mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
?>
```

and the cron job to schedule this script to run every 24 hours(using cpanel):

```
0   0   *   *   *   /usr/bin/php /home/domain/public_html/script.php
```

i know there may be other methods to do it but this is the most comfortable for me.